# C++ Type undefined reference to `vtable for Producer'

Tags: c++, gcc, vtable

I keep recieving error  undefined reference to `vtable for Producer'
for my sub class Producer :

```
#include "Producer.h"

Producer::Producer (unsigned int ID, int age1, std::string name1,
        char gender1, std::string jobDescription1)
        {IDNumber = ID; age = age1; name = name1;
        jobDescription = jobDescription1; gender = gender1;}

void SetJobDescription(std::string description){}

void PrintPersonnel(){cout<<"";}

Producer::~Producer(){}
```

the parent is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


class Personnel{
protected:
    unsigned int IDNumber;
    int age;
    std::string jobDescription;
    std::string name;
    char gender;
public:

    virtual void PrintPersonnel() = 0;

    unsigned int GetID();

    int GetAge();

    std::string Getname();

    std::string GetjobDescription();

    char GetGender();

    virtual ~Personnel();

};
```

//Personel.cpp

```
#include "Personnel.h"
unsigned int Personnel::GetID(){return IDNumber;}

int Personnel::GetAge(){return age;}

std::string Personnel::Getname(){return name;}

std::string Personnel::GetjobDescription(){return jobDescription;}

char Personnel::GetGender(){return gender;}

Personnel::~Personnel(){}
```

It has a pure virtual function.
why can't I implement the child class Producer?

thanks a lot.

Comment: My crystal ball says you haven't defined `~Personnel()`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I think I did define the destructor:#include "Producer.h"
    /*
     *Class Destructor.
     */
    Producer::~Producer(){}

Answer (score 2):

The problems in your code is that you forgot the scope of one member function. Try:

```
void Producer::PrintPersonnel(){cout<<"";} // Producer:: was missing
                                           // so you were defining a global function instead
                                           // of a member function.
```

Note that you have a similar problem with your definition of  `SetJobDescription()`.  As it is not a virtual function, it will just lead you to an undefined reference.

If it still not works, you should then define somewhere  `~Personnel()` as someone suggested in the comments.